# Python conditional code not working properly

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I've just started to learn python and can't get this code to work properly.

```
def percentage():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('First number:'))
            y = int(input('Second number:'))


            fraction = x/y
            percentage = fraction * 100
            final = "%d" % percentage

            return final

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass

        except ValueError:
            pass

if percentage() <= 1:
    print('E')

elif percentage() >= 99:
    print('F')

else:
    print(percentage(), "%")
```

The 'F' is printed only when I input x = 999 and y = 1000. Any other values just prompt the user again and again.
The code should output 'E' when the percentage function returns <= 1, 'F' when it returns >= 99 and the actual percentage number when any other value is returned.

Comment: This fails with a TypeError as `final` a string that you then try to compare with 1.

Comment: Your function returns a `str` but then you try to compare it to a number. Instead, you probably want to just return `percentage`. After fixing that you will still not have the desired functionality because every time your code gets to a point where it reads `percentage()`, it will call the function again. Instead you want to save the result of calling `percentage()` in a variable by doing `my_variable = percentage()` and then comparing and printing just with `my_variable`

Answer (score 4):

I am getting a type error as `final` is a string which you then try to compare with an integer.  The issue that you are asking about, however, is due to 3 calls of `percentage()`.  Instead call it once and assign the return value a variable then run your tests against the variable:

```
def percentage():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('First number:'))
            y = int(input('Second number:'))
            return 100 * x / y
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('x')
            pass
        except ValueError:
            print('y')
            pass


p = percentage() 
if p <= 1:
    print('E')
elif p >= 99:
    print('F')
else:
    print(p, "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your program so that your percentage function returns the `percentage` as a float instead of a string, and deal with the string formatting in your print statements.

We should also set some variable equal to the output of your function using something like `p = percentage()`, and then use `p` in your conditionals so that we don't unintentionally run percentage() multiple times from within your conditionals.

```
def percentage():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('First number:'))
            y = int(input('Second number:'))


            fraction = x/y
            percentage = fraction * 100
            # final = "%d" % percentage

            return percentage

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass

        except ValueError:
            pass

p = percentage()
if p < 1:
    print('E')

elif p >= 99:
    print('F')

else:
    print(f"{p:.2f}%")
```

Example program run:

```
First number:2
Second number:3
66.67%
```